# Thymeleaf set required if it is visible

Tags: jquery, html, thymeleaf

How can I set an input as required only if it is visible using thymeleaf `th:required` and perhaps jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf does server side proccessing of generating html pages. while generating page it knows nothing about visibility status on client. You need to add jQuery and following to set required which are visible on client.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:visible').attr('required', true);
})
```